# Haskell - list comprehension can't enumerate N × N

Tags: performance, list, haskell, list-comprehension

I have to write a function which returns a list of all pairs (x,y) where x,
y ∈ N , *and*:

- x is the product of two natural numbers (x = a • b, where a, b ∈ N) *and*
- x is really bigger than 5 but really smaller than 500, *and*
- y is a square number (y = c² where c ∈ N) NOT greater than 1000, *and*
- x is a divisor of y.

**My attempt:**

```hs
listPairs :: [(Int, Int)] 
listPairs = [(a*b, y) | y <- [0..], a <- [0..], b <- [0..], 
                        (a*b) > 5, (a*b) < 500, (y*y) < 1001, 
                        mod y (a*b) == 0]
```

But it doesn't return anything and the computer works a lot on it.

However if I choose a smaller range for `a`, `b` and `y` e. g. `[0..400]`, it takes up to a minute but it returns the right result.

So how could I solve the performance issue?

Comment: -1 you've already gotten tons of help from Haskell Cafe, please don't go from site to site asking for help (Danny Gratzer)

Comment: For reference to those that don't know what I'm talking about, this was asked by the OP and answered at length already this afternoon (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/haskell-cafe/fK1jJ3SSaUE)

Comment: `400` is too low. you should ensure you're not missing any correct solutions: `(a*b)<500, (a*b)>5, a==1, b==499` is consistent. So use `[1..499]` (`0*x > 5` is never true). OTOH `(y*y) < 1001` ==> `y < 32` so use `y<-[1..31], a<-[1..499]`. Should make it 32x faster. Then, `a*b < 500` and `a*b==b*a` so use `b<-[a..min 499 (div 500 a)]` which gives us another big reduction in problem size. Takes less than a second now.

Comment: btw you should be returning `[(a*b, y*y) | ...`, according to your description. `y` of your code is "c" of your description.

Comment: the specified duplicate answers a different question. This question is specific, that one is general.

Comment: @WillNess: post your comment as an answer!

Comment: @sclv done! (it was closed before, was it?)

Comment: @WillNess: quite possibly :-)

Answer (score 1):

So, of course nested list comprehensions on infinite lists do not terminate.

Fortunately, your lists are not infinite. There's a limit. If `x = a*b < 500`, then we know that it must be `a < 500` and `b < 500`. Also, `c = y*y < 1001` is just `y < 32`. So,

```
listPairs :: [(Int, Int)] 
listPairs = 
    [(x, c*c) | c <- [1..31], a <- [1..499],    -- a*b < 500 ==> b<500/a ,
                b <- [a..min 499 (div 500 a)],  -- a*b==b*a  ==> b >= a
                let x = a*b, x > 5,  
                -- (a*b) < 500, (c*c) < 1001,   -- no need to test this
                rem (c*c) x == 0]
```

`mod 0 n == 0` trivially holds, so I'm excluding 0 from "natural numbers" here.

There are still some duplicates produced here, even though we've limited the `b` value to `b >= a` in `x=a*b`, because `x` can have several representations (e.g. `1*6 == 2*3`).

You can use `Data.List.nub` to get rid of them.